# What is (are) the standard key(s) for a gui widget's action?

Tags: c++, user-interface

I know on Widows, this key is space, for example, space will perform the button's click which is its action,same for radio buttons etc. Is this the standard. If not, what is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, on a MS Window system these keys are handled by windows OS for navigation.

TAB move input focus to the next control.
TAB + SHIFT move input focus to the previous control.
ENTER Activate a button/menu.
SPACE check/uncheck a checkbox.
ALT activate the first menu group. Use arrows to navigate in menu.

UP/DOWN in a group, change radio button
ALT + DOWN In a combobox, open drop down list

There are probably more, but these are the on I came up with right now...

Was it this you had in mind?